# Upload images in Gridview from Assets folder via sqlitedatabase browser

Tags: android, gridview, android-sqlite

I am working on a project where I am having an ExpandableListView populated with Items and SubItems. When I click on SubItems, I have to populate relative images into the gridView. All the images are saved in Assets folder and I have to put there path in an external SqliteDatabase which I have created using sqlitedabase browser.

So my question is, How to save Path of images in database from Assets folder.

Comment: what is your assest folder structure can you mentioned that pleas?

Answer (score 0):

BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///android_asset/image/test.jpg")

Though storing Images in the Assets is not the best way to go. You will not be able to take advantage of the Android resource management system. So unless you have a compelling reason to do this, I'd suggest that you take a look at using the res folder and the resources system.

`BitmapFactory` has a method to decode a file via the decodeFile method.

Android lets you access a file in the assets folder via the **file:///android_asset/{path}** path.

if your file in assest>image folder and your image name is test.jpg

then **file:///android_asset/** is original path plus you need to mention remaining structure like **file:///android_asset/image/test.png**